# Properties of anonymous function as const in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am getting an error when trying to get the length of an anonymous array. I am wondering if I am just trying to do something that isn't allowed?

```
const gamearena = function ()
{
    var matrix = [];
    var height = 20;
    var width = 10;

    while(height--)
        matrix.push(new Array(width).fill(0));

    return matrix;
};
```

When I try to get the length of the array I get the error "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined".

I am using NetBeans and navigator seems to recognize the constant as an array. Should I just not use an anonymous function here?

Comment: Can you post more of your code? Where are you trying to access the "length" property?

Comment: I haven't written that far, I am just debugging in the console. Will that matter, though? Will the size of the array be accessible in some places and not in others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your constant **gamearena** is a function, not an array. You can log the length of the array like so:

```
console.log(gamearena().length);
```

and individual rows can be logged by:

```
for (var i = 0; i < gamearena().length; i++) {
    console.log(gamearena()[i]);
}
```

Comment: Adding the parenthesis... a little too simple. Thank you.